# Convert Excel to PDF - Embedded hyperlinks open as Files

Tags: excel, vba, pdf

I have Adobe Acrobat X Pro. When I create a file hyperlink in MS Excel 2010 and convert the spreadsheet (using VBA code) into a PDF, the link in PDF document is created as “open a web link” as opposed to “Open a File”.  A security warning always pops up when the link is clicked in the PDF document. Is there any way we can setup the hyperlink in Excel in such a way so that it opens the link as “Open a File” in execute menu item? Am I missing any parameter?

My code is :

```
pRng1.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
MyDirectory & "\CLOSING INDEX.pdf", Quality:= _
xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=False, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

Where ‘pRng1’ is the range on the spreadsheet.

Comment: How are you creating the hyperlinks?

Comment: ActiveCell.Offset(currentrow, 4).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ActiveCell.Offset(currentrow, 4), Address:=MyFilename

Comment: Is `MyFileName` a regular drive path, or a network (UNC) path?

Comment: Its randomly selected by the user. Could be C:\ drive or on network Q:\ drive.

Comment: I see the same thing - I don't think there's any way to alter that behavior from Excel.

Comment: What if I create a process to copy the selected files in a temporary folder on C:\ drive. Will that work?

Comment: I tested using my c drive - same security popup

Comment: Thanks for trying Tim.